# I'm trying to edit the width and height of a webpage in Chrome with HTML, using buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

Consider the code I have currently:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<input id="but" name="but" type=Button onclick="changeBCol();" value="Shuffle Background Colour"></input>
<br></br>
<button style="background-color:transparent;width:255;height:255" onclick = "w = w+1">Window width up</button>
<br></br>
<button style="background-color:transparent;width:255;height:255">Window width down</button>
<br></br>
<button style="background-color:transparent;width:255;height:255">Window height up</button>
<br></br>
<button style="background-color:transparent;width:255;height:255">Window height down</button>

<script>
var w = window.innerWidth
</script>

</html>
</body>
```

It currently doesn't work, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are just changing the value of the variable `w`(which does not contain a reference but a value), not the window's width nor its height.
Also **you only can change the width & height of windows opened by some script.**
I do not think it's good idea to try to change windows' width & height, but if you want to do it, consider using [window.resizeTo()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_resizeto.asp).

Plus:

1. Change `<br></br>` to `<br>`, `<input></input>` to `<input>`. They're [void elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-elements), which do not have their closing tags.
2. The inner for the inner, the outer for the outer: it should be `<html>...<body>...</body></html>`.
3. You should specify the `<button>`s' types, since the default is `type="submit"`.

## Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="author" content="K.">

        <title>Demo</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="demoButtons">
            <button id="incWidth" type="button">Increase its width</button>
            <button id="decWidth" type="button">Decrease its width</button>
            <button id="incHeight" type="button">Increase its height</button>
            <button id="decHeight" type="button">Decrease its height</button>
        </div>

        <script>
            let width = 100, height = 100;
            childWindow = window.open("", "", "width=100, height=100");
            childWindow.focus();

            document.getElementById("demoButtons").addEventListener("click", event => {
                    console.log(event.target.id);
                    /**/ if(event.target.id === "incWidth") width += 100;
                    else if(event.target.id === "decWidth" && width >= 100) width -= 100;
                    else if(event.target.id === "incHeight") height += 100;
                    else if(event.target.id === "decHeight" && height >= 100) height -= 100;
                    console.log(width, height);

                    childWindow.resizeTo(width, height);
                    childWindow.document.textContent = `The width: ${width}, the height: ${height}.`;
                    childWindow.focus();
                });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry if I seem a bit "green", but is it possible you could include an example in some code? Thanks :)

Comment: Attached a demo code. :)  Just remember these things: `let width = 100, height = 100;`, `childWindow = window.open("", "", "width=100, height=100");`, `childWindow.resizeTo(width, height);`.